# Ionic 3 Storage Capacity

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a big problem, i get this error :

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a
>   75497480 byte allocation with 16769216 free bytes and 49MB until OOM

How i manage local storage in ionic 3? Because i have application crash once per month and i get this error.

Thank You

Comment: on ios ? This may at least give you some debug advice: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11570

Comment: No, i use android.